# In SSRS, how to include first row from different dataset in tablix?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-expression, ssrs-2014, microsoft-reporting

I am creating a report, the purpose of which is to print a letter to many different people. Obviously each person's name, email, etc. will be different. For this I am using a list, which I understand uses a tablix.

Now inside each letter I also need some global data that comes from a dataset. For example, the company email, telephone number, etc. This data will be the same for every letter. However, every time I try to use some expression to get this, I get an error such as:

> The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox11’ refers to the
>   field ‘URL’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within
>   the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified
>   dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct
>   case.

The expression I'm using to get the above error is

`=LookupSet(true, true, Fields!URL, "SystemVars")`

I've tried other things but I can't figure out what I need to make it word.
Is there an expression I can use to solve this problem? If not, what steps should I take to get my letters working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the ".Value" portion in the expression. Try this:

```
=First(Fields!URL.Value, "SystemVars")
```

Comment: This worked. One of the things that was throwing off was the intellisense- after "Fields!" it would only allow fields from my other dataset. It ended up being easier to go into the Datasets menu and switch, then select the expression I wanted. I think I also had a related but separate error that was throwing me off. Thanks for your help!